# SQL works in php admin but returns empty result in php code

Tags: php, sql, admin

Here is my code:

```
  $usersql = "Select fab2_type from feesys_admin where adminname ='$_POST[username]' and adminemail = '$_POST[password]'";
        $userresult = mysql_query($usersql) or die ("<h3>Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()."</h3>");
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($userresult);
        if($num_rows > 0) {
            if($userresult['fab2_type']=='Partner'){
        }
```

When I run the SQL statement on the database through PHP Admin, it works fine. But it returns empty within the results here.

I checked to make sure the database connects fine.
I checked all spelling
Number of rows returns correctly.
No syntax errors.
When I echo the username and password and the sql statement, it's all correct.

This code used to work so I have no idea what's going wrong here.

Comment: Are your POST elements named? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. You also seem to be missing a closing brace `}`  if that's what you're actually using.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). *They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)*. See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: Please stop use the `mysql_*` API. Use `PDO` or `Mysqli` instead. And either escape them post parameters or use `prepared statements`. Your current code is very open for `SQL injections`.

Comment: Um... I think the OP gets the message. Edit: Ah, one comment deleted.

Comment: I thought you were chasing espresso @Fred-ii- ;)

Comment: Are you getting any errors @EKBlackwell?

Comment: @JayBlanchard That isn't the only *sweet* thing I'm chasin' ;)

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Still smackin'?*

Comment: Nah, I'm good now @Fred-ii-

Comment: No, Jay, I'm not getting any errors. Yes, Fred, my POST elements are named. I turned on error reporting and don't get any errors. The brace is only missing in the code snippet; the full code has the ending brace. If I change the SQL statements like you said to do, it still doesn't work. Neither does the password hash method.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have not quoted your `$_POST` array variables properly. You have `$_POST[username]` and `$_POST[password]`. It should be `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`. This causes PHP to interpret username and password as [**constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

Here is a different shot at your syntax -

```
$usersql = "SELECT `fab2_type` FROM `feesys_admin` WHERE `adminname` ='".$_POST['username']."' AND `adminemail` = '".$_POST['password']."' ";
```

You could further shorten this by predefining (as Fred says below).

```
$user = $_POST['username']; // please sanitize this
$pass = $_POST['password']; // please sanitize this
$usersql = "SELECT `fab2_type` FROM `feesys_admin` WHERE `adminname` ='".$user."' AND `adminemail` = '".$pass."' ";
```

You're very at risk for SQL injection if you don't clean up user input.

- [**Consult the following on Stack: How to prevent SQL Injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

---

**Password related**

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommed you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Plus, in regards to SQL injection,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: *Hm...*, TBH Jay, I'm not too sure about that. It would throw an error, pretty sure.

Comment: I did a quick test and in his example username and password are treated like undefined constants. Having said that there may need to be other editing to the query. I'll update my answer with that,

Comment: I tend to think that, setting up pre-defined variables is usually the easiest way, then doing `'".$var."'` type of thang. But, you are right about the constants thing.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can be more thorough here. Just barely finishing up cup number 2 while fielding questions in the office @Fred-ii-

Comment: Couldn't of done better myself +1 /// cup number 2? I'm up to 3 now, plus 2 Espressos, but only one gorgeous Italian beauty. ;)

Comment: Only one beauty? Slacker!

Comment: Yeah, she's that beautiful. I don't need another; she keeps me *off* my toes ;)

Comment: Check your Email btw.

Comment: I got it working. Moved where I call the field and played with the SQL statement. It's fine now. Thanks, everyone!